# Passing list into JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I'm passing list of beans into JSP and then I want to use JSTL to retrieve some data but nothing is populated just empty tag.
Any ideas?

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<jsp:useBean id="mailingbean" scope="request" class="com.dmd.jpa.Imp.AmpImp" />
<jsp:useBean id="mb" class="com.dmd.jpa.entity.Amp" /> 
<%
  mb = mailingbean.getResultProdInfo();

 %>
 <data>
 <item>
    <c:out value="<ColourCd> ${mb.apid} </ColourCd>"/>
 </item>
 </data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Scriptlets* and EL do not share the same variable scope. EL resolves variables as attributes of `PageContext`, `HttpServletRequest`, `HttpSession` and `ServletContext`. *Scriptlets* resolves variables which are been declared in the method or class scope only.

In this particular case, you basically need to set it as a request attribute:

```html
<%
  mb = mailingbean.getResultProdInfo();
  request.setAttribute("mb", mb);
%>
<data>
  <item>
    <c:out value="<ColourCd>${mb.apid}</ColourCd>" />
  </item>
</data>
```

However, this makes no sense. The following JSP bean declaration

```html
<jsp:useBean id="mailingbean" scope="request" class="com.dmd.jpa.Imp.AmpImp" />
```

will make it available by `${mailingbean}` already. So all you need to do is

```html
<data>
  <item>
    <c:out value="<ColourCd>${mailingbean.resultProdInfo.apid}</ColourCd>" />
  </item>
</data>
```

If you were doing the data loading job in the getter method, I'd move that to the constructor of the bean, there where this kind of job actually belongs.

```
public class AmpImp {

    private List<Amp> resultProdInfo;

    public AmpImp() {
        // Do the business job here.
        resultProdInfo = loadItSomehow();
    }

    public List<Amp> getResultProdInfo() {
        // Do NOT do the business job here. Just return the property.
        return resultProdInfo;
    } 

    // ...
}
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the bean is populated, try specifying the full bean as follows:

```
<c:out value="<ColourCd> ${mailingbean.resultProdInfo.apid} </ColourCd>" />
```

If you're going with just JSTL (and moving away from scriptlets), you can remove the `jsp:useBean` tags completely. It will attempt to pull the value out of the request by default, or whatever scope you specify.

Comment: that works but there is no way i can assign mailingbean.resultProdInfo into Amp so I'don't have to repeat mailingbean.resultProdInfo all the time?

Comment: @user1048282 `<c:set var="mb" value="${mailingbean.resultProdInfo}" />`